# Choosing the right selectors in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I'm new to jsoup and I'm having some difficulties to understand what selectors I should choose for the following html:

```
<div class="details">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>
     <b>
        Title :
    </b>
     dog
</div>
</div>
```

I need to do it for many html pages and each one has a different Title value (eg. dog, cat, etc.). So what should I do if I want my java code to get me ***only*** the "dog" word? Possibly in this format:

```
Elements links = doc.select(???);
```

I just need to know what to put in the "???" place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution will work if you only need to select a single instance from each page:

```
// select the first child of a div with class="details" that has a <b> tag child
Element titleDiv = doc.select("div.details div:has(b)").first();

// print out the text owned by the div (e.g. the animal's name)
System.out.println(titleDiv.ownText());
```

If you need to select multiple instances of this element on a single page, the following will also work:

```
// select all divs that have <b> and are children of div.details
Elements titleDivs = divs.select("div.details div:has(b)");

for (Element div : titleDivs) {

    // call ownText to get the animal name
    System.out.println(div.ownText());
}
```

For your sample HTML, both will print:

```
dog
```